# Set some billing data from the shipping fields in Woocommerce before processing payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, billing

I am using a payment method that require billing city, country and address to always be there, but I have set up a multistep checkout and in the first "billing" step, it only has firstname, lastname and email fields, then the in the second step "shipping" , it has the address, city, country…

But my payment plugin can not process the order because it requires the billing city, country and address to work.

Is there a way to obtain the billing city from the shipping city?

I have been searching but not found anything useful.

Any help or info will be appreciated

Comment: There is nothing better that I can't do for now.